# How to solve Link Error on call to ::UuidToString()?

Tags: com, visual-c++

I have included file "rpcdce.h" for ::UuidToString() function.

Still i am getting link error .
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Header files don't solve linker errors, they create them.  You'll have to add rpcrt4.lib to the linker's Input + Additional Dependencies setting.  Or paste this in your source code file:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib")
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379352%28VS.85%29.aspx - this seems to indicate that you need to link with Rpcrt4.lib.