# Compiler cannot find .lib file

Tags: c++, linker

I'm trying to compile project in visual studio with intel's compiler. The project compiles fine with visual studio and its own compiler, but when I switch to intel's compiler I get:
Error   1   error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'rpcrt4.lib'

Anybody knows how to correct it?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991941/how-to-solve-link-error-on-call-to-uuidtostring ?

Comment: I think the best way is to search the resolution in official guide of Intel's compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in your program using pragma like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "rpcrt4.lib");
```

Comment: Hi, I'd rather not edit that code, is there any other way to tell linker where that library is?

Comment: Yup if you are using cmake then you can link through cmakelists of your module. If You are using visual studio then you can give in your linker options.